# CSS Style: Video-js - center and text-align: center; is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i don't know wher is the problem here in my video or in the css code?

```html
<center>
<div class="video-js-responsive-container vjs-hd">
    <video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls
 preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
       <source src="<?php echo $linkdown?>" type='video/mp4' width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
       <source poster="<?php echo $posterimg; ?>">
    </video>
</div>
</center>
```

i can't remove this css beaucose i need this css code!maybe it should be modified?

```css
<style>
.video-js-responsive-container.vjs-hd {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.video-js-responsive-container.vjs-sd {
    padding-top: 75%;
}
.video-js-responsive-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.video-js-responsive-container .video-js {
    height: 75%; 
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}
body{
background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
.video-js-responsive-container .video-js {
    height: 75%; 
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

Comment: no is not working is center now, but now i see just the play button!

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle that recreates your issue we can't help you with this little information: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `top` and `left` of the inner element to `25% / 2 = 12.5%`:

```
.video-js-responsive-container .video-js {
    height: 75%; 
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.5%;
    left: 12.5%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the problem is when i do full screen, 12.5% is out , so in full screen i see 87.5% !!?

Comment: Did you test it? Fullscreen should still work as expected imo.

Comment: Thanks for your help man, i have fix that problem now, i don't know why i can't close my post now.

Answer (score 0):

**this was the correct code CSS, I found it after three hours **

```css
<style>
.video-js-responsive-container.vjs-hd {
    padding-top: 35.50%;
}
.video-js-responsive-container.vjs-sd {
    padding-top: 55%;
}
.video-js-responsive-container {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
}
.video-js-responsive-container .video-js {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
body{
background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
</style>
```